# Angular 1.x directive controller promise issue in ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have a directive in which I am calling `promise` function inside `constructor`.Below is the snippet of it

```
 class exampleController {
       constructor(exampleService) {
         var vm = this;
         vm.itemLoaded = false;

         exampleService.getSomeData().then(function(response){
            vm.data = response;
            vm.itemLoaded = true;
         }
       }
    }    
    angular.module('exampleApp').controller('exampleController',exampleController)
.directive('exampleDirective', exampleDirective)
 .service('exampleService', exampleService);

    class exampleDirective {
      constructor(){
        this.controller = 'exampleController';
        this.controllerAs = 'vm';
      }
    }

    function exampleService() {
       getData: function () {
          return $http.get('url');
       }
    }
```

In template if I call

```
<example></example>
<example></example>
<example></example>
```

The updation of itemLoaded scope goes to last directive though each directive have it's respective async function got called and I also add a break point in promise function and for second/third directive I am getting first `directive` value.It's behaving like a singleton directive sharing same address for all 3 directive.

Anyone face this type of issue?I am using babel to convert it into ES5

Comment: `exampleService` is the singleton here. You need to make it generate a new promise every time a caller needs one, e.g. `exampleService.getData().then(...) // Unique per call of getData()`

Comment: @RGraham you mean to say I have to add `new` keyword exampleService??

Comment: @RGraham no there is function I updated my question

Comment: can you provide sample for `exampleService.getSomeData()`?

Comment: @Grundy updated my question

Comment: how you set url? is it same for all?

Comment: @Grundy no its different

Comment: but how you setup it for each directive? from code in question, i see that eaxh directive run request to same url, so, they get same result. Can you provide sample plunkr, that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102323/discussion-between-grundy-and-arpit).